# SBT Docker ADD file not found

Tags: docker, sbt

I have one SBT docker file and i want to add one SH script to my container so i use :

```
dockerBaseImage := "frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:latest" //use JRE 8 base image
dockerCommands := dockerCommands.value.flatMap {
 case cmd@Cmd("FROM", _) => List(cmd, Cmd("RUN", "apk update && apk add bash"))
 case cmd@Cmd("ADD", _) => List(cmd, Cmd("ADD", "wait-for-it.sh /"))
 case other => List(other)
}
```

but when i try to build my image, console tell me :
"wait-for-it.sh no such file o directory.

The SBT file is in the same directory than the SH file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
mappings in Universal += file("wait-for-it.sh") -> "wait-for-it.sh"
```